# Good ways of converting letters to numbers in naive RSA implementation?

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, character-encoding, rsa

I'm implementing a short RSA program and have this code:

```
private string Encrypt(string data)
{
    BigInteger dataAsBigInteger = new BigInteger(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

    BigInteger remainder = BigInteger.ModPow(dataAsBigInteger, exponentE, CalculatePublicKey());

    return Convert.ToBase64String(remainder.ToByteArray());
}

private string Decrypt(string data)
{
    BigInteger dataAsBigInteger = new BigInteger(Convert.FromBase64String(data));

    BigInteger remainder = BigInteger.ModPow(dataAsBigInteger, CalculatePrivateKey(), CalculatePublicKey());

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(remainder.ToByteArray());
}
```

Unfortunately, I seem to be getting weird ASCII values for the result. I tried with just using numbers instead of text and `Decrypt(Encrypt(number)) == number` so I know the algorithm is fine so I think it is messing up because of converting to and from byte arrays and performing operations on them.

If this didn't work I was thinking of a better idea for a formula of converting letters to numbers. I can't do `A = 1, B = 2, etc.` because 11 would be ambiguous with `K (11th letter)`. Maybe if each letter's position `(A = 1, B = 2, etc.)` was first multiplied by 10 and then you would know the next letter began at a non-zero value?

Is something like this advisable or can the byte arrays be salvaged?

Comment: [This example](http://xmight.blogspot.com/2011/07/multithreaded-rsa-encryption-with-keys.html) might help you.

Comment: @L.B: That would work if data was a number, but I'm trying to encrypt a string of letters.

Comment: How large is your public modulus?

Comment: @KarolS: I'm using `p = 53, q = 59, e = 3`

Comment: @KarolS: Oh ok I used a huge number and it worked now. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: The modulus must be larger than the message.

Comment: Future readers behold: the code in the question performs *textbook RSA*. Textbook RSA is **not cryptographically secure**, please use a secure padding scheme instead (currently that means OAEP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle your scheme should work, as long as the resulting `BigInteger` is not negative or larger than the modulus.

---

If a cryptographically secure RSA implementation such as OAEP is used then you also need to subtract the overhead of the padding. Usually though you should only encrypt a symmetric key and use [hybrid cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) to allow for almost arbitrary message sizes.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you are trying to do does not make sense.  RSA can only encrypt *fixed-length* messages, integers of the same order-of-magnitude as the public modulus *n*.  (Specifically, if the plaintext *m*, taken as a number, is small enough that *m<sup>e</sup> < n*, then the encryption is trivially reversible, and if it is *larger* than *n*, it can't be encrypted at all.)

Moreover, you appear to be attempting to implement "[textbook RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa)", which is *insecure*.  You need to redesign your application so that, instead, it uses RSA as part of a [key encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) scheme, which securely delivers a symmetric (e.g. AES) key which is used, in an [authenticated operation mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), to encrypt the actual message.

This correction to your design will also render your encoding problem moot, since the message proper is now being encrypted using a symmetric cipher that operates on bit streams rather than numbers.

I would be very surprised if C# does not have libraries that do this for you.

Comment: C# does have libraries but I'm implementing it just to understand the basics of the algorithm, hence the "naive" in the title.

Comment: @JohnSmith In that case, try your hand at implementing [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAEP).  That will teach you the fundamentals of RSA *and* (part of) how to use it securely.

Comment: I might but I'd first like to finish this and learn how to properly convert letters to numbers for use in the algorithm.

Comment: @JohnSmith What you're trying to do doesn't make sense, even as an exercise.  I've added a paragraph attempting to explain why.

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't downvote you but for some reason people seem to disagree with what you're saying.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, I am certain.

Comment: Well I just changed my primes to be large numbers and it works perfectly now so I don't think you're right unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @JohnSmith You've either implemented something that *resembles* RSA but has different mathematical properties, or you've implemented textbook RSA with a "padding" scheme you made up in ignorance of the required mathematical properties for *that*. In either case, your code is (a) insecure, (b) probably does not round trip all inputs, (c) may not even conform to the definition of a public-key cryptosystem anymore! I'm certain about this because the *premises of your question* indicate that you don't understand what RSA can and cannot do and how it must be used if it is to be any good at all.

Comment: @JohnSmith You need to read http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/oae.pdf and http://www.shoup.net/papers/oaep.pdf . You need to understand *every detail* of both papers. If they don't make sense, you need to do background reading on public key cryptosystems and their mathematical foundations until they *do* make sense.

Comment: I am not sure why people would down-vote this answer, as it's correct and helpful. Sure, the tone might *seem* a bit arrogant, but sometimes the gulf between ignorance and competence is so great that it's impossible to bridge without a little condescension. It's hard to learn much without letting go of pride once in a while.

Comment: I downvoted for two reasons. First of all the question already indicated that the writer knew the RSA to be unsafe from the beginning. Furthermore, this answer did not *actually answer the question*. If you want to leave warnings, that's fine. Use a comment.

Comment: @owlstead I really don't see how you got that impression; it's *my* impression that the OP still doesn't realize that he must avoid having $m^e < n$, which I would consider a baseline for understanding. I sympathize with your "doesn't answer the question" reaction - I've been on the other side of that a few times myself - but in this case I think it is inappropriate to answer the question literally asked; the stakes are too high.

Comment: You cannot learn crypto all in one go. The author at least indicated that he was aware of the risks. After that you only need to warn other users. That's a fine thing to do, but if I would look at it your way - not answering the question but showing another way around it - then I would only answer about 10% of the actual questions. In the end the users will have to take some responsibility as well; if they simply copy any code (including mine) from the internet without understanding, then they are already lost. I am actually contemplating linking to some kind of crypto report in the comments.